# How can I debug a JSP?

Tags: java, ide, debugging, jsp, intellij

I'm trying to edit a JSP for a project and I'm getting a NullPointerException somewhere in the JSP when it's requested from my server.

My web server (JBoss) is reporting the exception, but it's giving me a bogus line number. It's reporting that the exception happened on line 702, but my JSP is only 146 lines long, so I'm unable to identify which line is choking.

What are some good techniques to debug errors in JSPs? I'm using IntelliJ 9 Ultimate as my IDE.

Thanks

Comment: may be asked on Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I'm not entirely clear on the difference between StackOverflow.com and Programmers.StackExchange.com. I'm not sure which questions belong where.. I've read the FAQ for programmers.stackexchange but it's a little vague.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that this would be OK on Stack Overflow. While it's fairly specific there's not enough concrete detail (due to the nature of the problem). What you are after is debugging techniques which should be on topic for this site.

Comment: have you included any jsps inside your jsp ? That's how the line number may increase . Question need to be moved to stackoverflow

Comment: One technique is seeing compile files:http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-debug-jsp-with-help-of-compiled.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are several options that can help you:

1. This answer actually explains how to debug JSPs specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739/jsp-debugging-in-intellij-idea.  I haven't ever tried this so I followed the next three suggestions when I was using JSP, JBoss, and IntelliJ...
2. Remember that JSPs are compiled to classes. When it says line 702, it means in the compiled class. If you have `test.jsp`, the class name is probably `test_jsp`, so open your JBoss work directory and search for `test_jsp.java` (once you find the right directory, you'll see that the directory structure matches your JSP directory structure).  Whenever I had a JSP exception I could find the line quite easily and usually match it up to the corresponding line in the JSP.
3. Breakpoints work just fine in Java classes *called* from a JSP.  So, maybe you can move the Java script code that you have in your JSP into a class and debug from the entry point.  In the future you can also make a habit of rearranging your logic so that the majority of it is in a class that is being called from the JSP, and the JSP is simple, straightforward and hopefully not throwing any exceptions.  This is good practice anyway.
4. Better yet, remove all (or virtually all) Java logic into Java classes, leaving JSPs for HTML and JSP tags. I know this isn't feasible right away, but again, it's a good idea long term to avoid problems like this.

Comment: +1 for removing logic from the JSP.  More on this can be seen in the JSP/Servlet best practices, with Model 2 (MVC) architecture: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/servlets-jsp-140445.html

Comment: Thanks! Option 4 is ideal, I agree, but we don't have great view/controller separation in this project.

Comment: Also +1 for item #2. I had no idea where to find the `*_jsp.java` classes.

Comment: removing all logic from JSPs on a project that has thousands of JSPs, each containing several thousand lines of scriptlets... no, thanks, just want to debug the Hashtables and Vectors. FML :-( </rant> nice answer though

Answer (score -1):

You can debug a JSP page easily just like a java code:
"a JSP file is the same like debugging a Java class, but the most features (Watch, Inspect, etc) are not implemented. The only way to get the values of variables is the Variables view."
See the link below:
 https://www.laliluna.de/articles/posts/debugging-jsp-java-tutorial.html

Comment: When answering an older question that already has a well received answer, please add more detail to your answer so that you are addressing something that wasn't already covered.